# Painting colored text to c++ win32

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to paint colored text to what I've already done?

I've tried `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`, `CreateSolidBrush()`, and several other functions.

```
//-----------------------------------
// Learning the win32 API for C++
//
// Created by: Cosmic Cruizer
//-----------------------------------

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Function declarations
bool SetUpWindowClass (char*, int, int, int);         // Remove window structure from WinMain and put into function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)  // Pre-declare Windows procedure/function

// Global variables
const char CLASS_NAME[] = "My Window Class Array";    // declared for window class; Can be static or const


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
  //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
  HWND hwnd{};                                       // This is the handle for our window
  MSG msg{};                                         // Handle for messages to the application
  SetUpWindowClass (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);         // The Window structure - removed from main and made into a function

  // Step 2: Creating the Window
  hwnd = CreateWindowEx(             // returns a handle to the new window, or zero if the function fails
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,                // Optional window styles. Can be set to 0
    CLASS_NAME,                      // Name of window class, see set 1b. Also set as the constant
    "My First C++ Windows App",      // Window title text
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,             // Window style, title bar, a border, a system menu, and Minimize and Maximize buttons.
    200, 200, 500, 400,              // Size and position
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);    // Parent window, Menu, Instance handle, Additional app data

  // Add an exit button
   CreateWindow(
    "BUTTON",                        // Predefined class; Unicode assumed
    "EXIT",                          // Button text
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles
    200, 200, 60, 25,                // x position, y position, Button width, Button height
    hwnd,                            // Parent window
    NULL,                            // No menu.
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);   // Pointer not needed.

  ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);        // Make the window visible on the screen


  // Step 3: The Message Loop
  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)  {       // Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0
    TranslateMessage(&msg);          // Translate virtual-key messages into character messages
    DispatchMessage(&msg);           // Send message to WindowProcedure
  }

  return msg.wParam;
}

//---------- Functions ----------//

// Setup the window structure
bool SetUpWindowClass (char *cpTitle, int iR, int iG, int iB) {
  //Step 1a:  The Window structure
  WNDCLASSEX wc{};                            // Data structure for the windowclass
  wc.cbSize            = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);  // Sets the size of the Windows API
  wc.style             = 0;                   // define additional elements of the window class
  wc.lpfnWndProc       = WndProc;             // defines most of the behavior of the window. See setp 4 "LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc" function
  wc.cbClsExtra        = 0;                   // No extra bytes after the window class
  wc.cbWndExtra        = 0;                   // structure for the window instance
  wc.hInstance         = GetModuleHandle (NULL); // handle to the application instance.
  wc.hIcon             = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);   // handle to icon class, if NULL, system provides a default icon.
  wc.hCursor           = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);       // handle to cursor class
  wc.hbrBackground     = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+18);         // Add color as the background of the window
  wc.lpszMenuName      = NULL;                // No menu
  wc.lpszClassName     = CLASS_NAME;          // string that identifies the window class
  wc.hIconSm           = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

  //Step 1b:  Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program
  if (RegisterClassEx (&wc)) return true;
  else return false;
}


// Step 4: the Window Procedure in this function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  switch(uMsg){
    case WM_CLOSE:{
      DestroyWindow(hwnd);
      break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:{               // Close the window when exit is pressed
      if (MessageBox(hwnd, "Really quit?", "Exit Warning", MB_OKCANCEL) == IDOK){ // what the hell, just wanted this.
        PostQuitMessage(0);
       }
         break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:{
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
    }

//--- trying to create colored text ---//
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:{
      HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;             // handle to display context
      hwnd = (HWND) lParam; // handle to control window
      SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(100,255,255));
      SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(250,250,6));
      return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(250,250,100));
    }
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:{
      HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
      SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,255));
      SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,230,0));
      return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,230,0));
    }


    case WM_PAINT:{                     // All painting (text) occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;                   // Holds info about current painting session.
      HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);  // Create the device context (DC)

      // Each character is added to the cpaText array. Then the for loop goes through and paints each character
      int iY = 7;                       // Vertical spaces and number of lines for the array
      const char *cpaText [iY] = {      // changed from char to const char to get rid of warning. and added 1 for each line and a return
        "Hello Peoples",
        "",
        "This is my first attempt to program using the Win32 API.",
        "I can only hope it gets better with time.",
        "",
        "Created by \"The\" Cosmic Cruizer"
      };
      for (int iLoopCounter = 0; cpaText [iLoopCounter] != 0; iLoopCounter++, iY += 20) {
        TextOut (hdc, 5, iY, cpaText [iLoopCounter], strlen (cpaText [iLoopCounter]));
      }

      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);              // Free up HDC created with BeginPaint
      break;
    }
    default:{
      return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // Return is needed either here or at the end
      break;
    }
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // Return is needed either here or in the default case
}
```

Comment: apparently you use SetTextColor

Comment: @user253751 the important part is that it needs to be in the `WM_PAINT` handler, after you've created the HDC but before you call `TextOut`.

Comment: by the way, congratulations for doing your research and *not* asking a stupid question. E.g. when someone said to use `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`, you actually wrote a sensible handler for it and didn't just try to shove the word `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` in random places in your code, like some people would :) (I think your handler still leaks brushes)

Answer (score 3):

`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` and `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` are notification messages used by [`STATIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-controls)/[`EDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls) controls, neither of which you have on your window, so you will never receive those messages and should remove those handlers from your code.

You are trying to draw colored text directly onto your window using `TextOutA()` in a `WM_PAINT` handler, which is fine. But per the [`TextOutA()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textouta):

> The TextOut function writes a character string at the specified location, **using the currently selected font, background color, and text color.**

Your `WM_PAINT` handler is not selecting *anything* into the `HDC` that `BeginPaint()` returns, before trying to draw on it.  It simply needs to configure the desired font/color values as desired, eg:

```cpp
HFONT hFont;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  switch(uMsg){
    ...
    case WM_CREATE:{
      hFont = CreateFont(...); // or CreateFontIndirect()
      break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:{
      DeleteObject(hFont);
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
    }

    case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
    case WM_FONTCHANGE:{
      DeleteObject(hFont);
      hFont = CreateFont(...); // or CreateFontIndirect()
      InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
      break;
    }

    case WM_PAINT:{
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
      HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

      HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT) SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
      SetTextColor(hdc, ...);
      SetBkColor(hdc, ...);

      int iY = 7;
      const char *cpaText [iY] = {
        "Hello Peoples",
        "",
        "This is my first attempt to program using the Win32 API.",
        "I can only hope it gets better with time.",
        "",
        "Created by \"The\" Cosmic Cruizer"
      };
      for (int iLoopCounter = 0; cpaText [iLoopCounter] != 0; iLoopCounter++, iY += 20) {
        TextOutA (hdc, 5, iY, cpaText [iLoopCounter], strlen (cpaText [iLoopCounter]));
      }

      SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);

      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
      return 0;
    }
    ...
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: That was too easy after all the days of head butting I did. I originally tried SetTextColor and SetBkColor in WM_PAINT, but totally missed  CreateFont and the SelectObject.

I deleted case statements for WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC and WM_CTLCOLOREDIT. Still working on/playing with HFONT hFont = CreateFont(...). There's a lot of interesting options, but it works!

Thank's for TexOut explanation. After you explained it and showed me what to do it was kind of a forehead slapper. Also, thank you for making sure I did the cleanup. It was on my mind, but your addition made sure it was not forgotten.

Comment: You really don't want to do `CreateFont` inside the `WM_PAINT` handler, which will be called many, many times over the lifetime of the window.  It's sufficient to get the `HFONT` one time as long as you call `SelectObject` with in on every `WM_PAINT`.  Pedantically, you should `DeleteFont` and `CreateFont` again on `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` and `WM_FONTCHANGE` but most runs of the program will probably not see either of these messages even once.

Comment: @BenVoigt good point about creating the font only once.  I have updated my example to demonstrate this.

Comment: I tried moving CreateFont to WM_CREATE, but I'm getting an error. (Not going to explain the error cause I want to try and resolve it myself.) Need to stop playing today, but will hopefully get back to it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Got my error figured out. It was an easy one. Needed to declare hFont. I put it up under my global variables. Now I see you have it there, I just didn't catch it. 

You also added WM_SETTINGCHANGE and WM_FONTCHANGE. I went and read up on them, but am not sure why you added them. I played with them and they do not make any differences at this time. Right now I have them commented out unit I can figure out what to do with them.

Comment: @Mr.Coz "*am not sure why you added them*" - because the user can change system/locale settings that MIGHT affect the font you have loaded, so you should reload the font again if the system/locale config does change.

Comment: Ah now I see. Kind of helping to set me up for my continued learning and progress. :)  I did read about registry settings and other items changing, just wasn't sure why. Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Coz well, for instance, think of what happens if the user uninstalls the font you are using. Or installs a new font that is a better match to the criteria you pass to `CreateFont/Indirect()`. Or if you are using a font charset that is tied to the user's locale, and the locale changes.